# Combining two lists to make an Xlsxwriter row

Tags: python, for-loop, xlsxwriter, worksheet-function, worksheet

Given two lists of strings (year and quarter), make an excel row like this:

```
"2001 q1", "2001 q2", ..., "2008 q3", "2008 q4"
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
import xlsxwriter
from xlsxwriter import workbook

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('template.xlsx')
worksheet_data = workbook.add_worksheet( "data" )

year = ["2001 ", "2002 ", "2003 ", "2004 ", "2005 ", "2006 ", "2007 ", "2008 "]
quarter = ['q1 ', 'q2 ', 'q3 ', 'q4 ']

for x in year:
    for y in quarter:
        worksheet_data.write_row(
          "A1",       #start cell
          [x + y]
        )

workbook.close()
```

I need this for a clients customized tables.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope it helps:**

```
import xlsxwriter
from xlsxwriter import Workbook

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('template.xlsx')
worksheet_data = workbook.add_worksheet("data")
data = []

year = ["2001 ", "2002 ", "2003 ", "2004 ", "2005 ", "2006 ", "2007 ", "2008 "]
quarter = ['q1 ', 'q2 ', 'q3 ', 'q4 ']

for x in year:
    for y in quarter:
        data.append(x + y)
worksheet_data.write_row(0, 0, data)
workbook.close()
```

*write_row(0, 0, data)* is zero indexed, so this is A1.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to write str(x+y) into "A1" you may need to format your request like this:

```
write_row(1, 1, str(x+y))
```

ref: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html

Style-wise, I'd also recommend:

- not putting the spaces in your `year` and `quarter` arrays, but rather add them when consuming those values, e.g.: `combined = str(x + " " + y)`
- looping over a range instead of manually-created list of (contiguous + numeric) years: `range(2001, 2008+1)`